# reacti-native friendly library with Browserify?

Tags: node.js, react-native

I am writing a library to be use by react-native, my dependencies is using a lot ofnodejs library like `crypto, fs, https, http` ...

I am trying to resolve the library below:

crypto: require.resolve('crypto-browserify'),

```
  fs: require.resolve('react-native-fs'),
  http: require.resolve('stream-http'),
  https: require.resolve('https-browserify'),
  process: require.resolve('process/browser.js'),
  stream: require.resolve('readable-stream'),
  tls: require.resolve('tls-browserify'),
  net: require.resolve('net-browserify'),
  util: require.resolve('util/util.js'),
  punycode: require.resolve('punycode/'),
  url: require.resolve('react-native-url'),
  querystring: require.resolve('querystring-es3/'),
  zlib: require.resolve('react-zlib-js'),
  path: require.resolve('react-native-path'),
  vm: require.resolve('vm-browserify')
```

I have seen example of using tradle/rn-nodeify to create shim.js in react-native project.

My question is how can I create a react native friendly library, without react-native developer going through the hassle to use my library?

Browserify my project?